# Why is OpenCv Imgproc.cvtColor returning only contours?

Tags: java, android, opencv

In the following method I'm trying to filter pixels out of the input RGB frame.  I convert it to HSV as I've learned for ingest by the inRange function.  The issue is that the output image only contains contours.  From all the examples I've seen and followed I should get filled in shapes. Can anyone tell what's going on?

```
private Mat ColorSelect(int request, Mat inRGB)
{
    Mat outMat = new Mat(inRGB.height(), inRGB.width(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    // Convert input image to HSV
    Mat hsv_image = new Mat ();
    Mat filtered = new Mat (inRGB.height(), inRGB.width(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    Mat dialated = new Mat (inRGB.height(), inRGB.width(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    int erosion_size = 7;

    Mat element = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new  Size(2*erosion_size + 1, 2*erosion_size+1));
    Imgproc.cvtColor(inRGB, hsv_image, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV,0);

     // Threshold the HSV image, keep only the desired color's pixels
    if(request == 1)
    {
        Core.inRange(hsv_image, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), filtered);//lower_red_hue
    }
    if(request == 2)
    {
        Core.inRange(hsv_image, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), filtered);//mid_red_hue
    }
    if(request == 3)
    {
        Core.inRange(hsv_image, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), filtered);//upper_red_hue
    }
    if(request == 4)
    {
        Core.inRange(hsv_image, new Scalar(25, 10, 100), new Scalar(35, 255, 255), filtered);//yellow_hue
    }
    if(request == 5)
    {
        Core.inRange(hsv_image, new Scalar(200, 255, 255), new Scalar(0, 200, 200), filtered);//light_blue_hue
    }
    if(request == 6)
    {
        Core.inRange(hsv_image, new Scalar(115, 10, 100), new Scalar(125, 255, 255), filtered);//blue_hue
    }
    Imgproc.dilate(filtered, dialated, element);
    Mat element1 = Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new  Size(2*erosion_size + 1, 2*erosion_size+1));
    Imgproc.erode(dialated, outMat, element1);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(filtered, outMat, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGB,0);
    return outMat;
}
```

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please attach a sample input and output image.

Comment: Ok, let me add a function to capture the images.

Comment: @DanMašek Here are links to some screensnaps.  The first should be of the input image and the next two are output.  The contour dances so a movie would have been better but you can only see the outline of the blue square, which is actually red.  From examples I would have expected the square to be filled in not a contour.
![url=http://postimg.org/image/lvx9xj7y9/](http://postimg.org/image/lvx9xj7y9/).
![url=http://postimg.org/image/8qhrrfe2p/](http://postimg.org/image/8qhrrfe2p/), 
![url=http://postimg.org/image/xihdynv9d/](http://postimg.org/image/xihdynv9d/).

Comment: Some of your ranges are wrong: `new Scalar(200, 255, 255), new Scalar(0, 200, 200)` won't work, the [first is the lower bound, second is the upper bound](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange). Can you please label those images? How do they relate to each other? What request was that? Just playing with this in Python, it seems your ranges are too tight, especially for value.

Comment: @DanMašek Sorry, agree about the ranges but all the images are related to a search for red objects.
    Core.inRange(hsv_image, new Scalar(0, 100, 100), new Scalar(10, 255, 255), filtered);//mid_red_hue

Comment: And the first one (the one with the picture of the screen), that's already converted to HSV and then saved as BGR?

Comment: @DanMašek The picture was an inputframe.rgba() input converted to HSV and back.

I've figured out what was causing the resulting image only having contours.  After the image comes out of this function I run it through findcontour and apparently it is over-writing the image with the found contours. So I believe this case is closed.

Comment: Oh, `findContours`, yeah. That was my first suspicion (because I've seen that multiple times), but since you didn't show it in your sample, I discounted that possibility. You can probably delete this question, since the problem is not in the code shown.